# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value.trigger is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to display selected form items on the console and trigger whenever user changes his/her selection.

I am getting below error in it,

```
options-general.php?page=my-unique-identifier:397 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value.trigger is not a function
```

Here is my code,

```
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '      <h3>Form:</h3>
                <form>
                    Provide PDF Link:<br>
                    <input type="url" id="url" name="url" placeholder="http://">
                    <br><br>
                    Select Flipbook Theme:<br>
                    <input type="radio" id="theme" name="theme" value="bible" checked> Bible<br>
                    <input type="radio" id="theme" name="theme" value="magazine"> Magazine<br>
                    <input type="radio" id="theme" name="theme" value="magazine single"> Magazine Single<br><br>
                    <button type="button">Get Code</button><br> 
                </form>
                    <div id="code" style="background-color:green;">
                    </div>
                    <div id="preview">
                    <h3>Preview:</h3>
                    </div>
                <script>    
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                        var url = document.getElementById("url").value.trigger("change");
                        var theme = document.getElementById("theme").value.trigger("change");
                        console.log(theme);
                    }); 
                </script>
        ';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: What do you expect with `.trigger("url")` ? `trigger` is a method of `jQ` wrapped object by the way!

Comment: @RayonDabre: It was a syntax error which I just fixed. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: `"trigger` is a method of `jQ` wrapped object!"... `$("#url").trigger('change')`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
var url = document.getElementById("url").value.trigger("url");
```

When you access the property `.value` of a [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) you will have a `String`. The `String` will not have a `.trigger` property you can call as a function.

Here's a clarification of what's happening:

```
var element = document.getElementById("url"); // some DOM node
var val = element.value;                      // a string like "hello"
val.trigger("url");                           // ERROR!

val.trigger;                                  // undefined

// Essentially you're doing this:
undefined();                                  // ERROR!
```

### Update

It looks like you're trying to detect a changed value and do something when that happens. Try something like this (untested):

```
jQuery("#url").on("change", function() {
  var newValue = this.value;
  // do other things when value changes...
});
```

Comment: So I believe I should first detect a change and then get the value. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I was able to identify the problem, but I'm not entirely sure what your intentions are with the code. You may want something like `jQuery("#url").on("change", function() { var newValue = this.value; /* do other things when value changes... */ })`